# Loading same image with `image_tag` does not evaluate to same path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I don’t know enough about Rails for understanding what is happening here.
I am trying to load an image and I have:

- `item.logo == "my-cool-image.gif”` => `True`
- `item.logo.class` => `String`
- Rails version: 4.2.0
- Asset pipeline: yes

this is my code:

`<%= image_tag "my-cool-image.gif" %>
<%= image_tag item.logo %>`

and it evaluates to:

`<img src="/my-app/my-cool-image.gif" alt="My cool image”>
<img src="/images/my-cool-image.gif" alt="My cool image”>`

Why is it trying to load the image from a different path?

How can I make `<%= image_tag item.logo %>` load the image from where `<%= image_tag "my-cool-image.gif" %>` is loading it?

Comment: which version of rails? Are you using the asset pipeline?  is `item` and instance of an Item model? does it include anything like carrier wave, etc..  are  you 100% sure that `item.logo == "my-cool-image.gif"` ?(ie is the == meant to show equality or comparison). Does `Item` have modules or gems messing with logo (if it is stored in the DB).     `image_tag` internally calls `image_path` which eventually calls `asset_path` to locate the image. so you can see what it is doing if you trace the code.

Comment: Item is an instance of an Item presenter. Rails 4.2.0. Item is not stored in the database. I am using the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force using your Path:

```
<%= image_tag "/my-app/#{item.logo}" %>
```